# how to use mongodb java-driver Projections.slice

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use Aggregates.project to slice the array in my documents.
My documents is like

```
{
"date":"",
"stype_0":[1,2,3,4]
}
```

in the mongochef looks like
[image: the document]

and my code in java is :

```
Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(
                                Projections.slice("stype_0", pst-1, pen-pst),Projections.slice("stype_1", pst-1, pen-pst),
                                Projections.slice("stype_2", pst-1, pen-pst),Projections.slice("stype_3", pst-1, pen-pst))))
```

finally i get error

```
First argument to $slice must be an array, but is of type: int
```

I guess that is because the first element in stype_0 is int , but I really do not know why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slice has two versions. [`$slice(aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) & [`$slice(projection)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/projection/slice/). You are using the wrong one.

Aggregate slice function doesn't have any built-in support. Below is an example for one such projection. Do the same for all the other projection fields.

```
List stype_0 = Arrays.asList("$stype_0", 1, 1);    
Bson project = Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(new Document("stype_0", new Document("$slice", stype_0))));
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(project));
```